# Helm Error: INSTALLATION FAILED : manifests contain a resource that already exists

Tags: helm

When I run the helm command to install `my-mysql-operator`, I get

```
helm install my-mysql-operator mysql-operator/mysql-operator --namespace mysql-operator --create-namespace
```

I get the following error,

> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ClusterRole "mysql-operator" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "mysql-operator": current value is "mysql"

So so the resource exists, how do I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see everything helm has installed with

```
helm list --all-namespaces
```

Which should return something like this

```
❯ helm list --all-namespaces
NAME                    NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION 
my-mysql-operator       mysql           1               2022-05-26 12:18:28.652497947 -0500 CDT deployed        mysql-operator-2.0.4    8.0.29-2.0.4
```

The problem here is that the resource `my-mysql-operator` is currently installed into the `mysql` namespace. In order to delete it and recreate it you can do,

```
helm uninstall -n mysql my-mysql-operator
```

Then you should be able to run the above command.